# How to fix optimazition error publish in play store

Tags: ionic4

my apk is 1.4MB but error is "This APK results in unused code and resources being sent to users. Your app could be smaller if you used the Android App Bundle. By not optimizing your app for device configurations, your app is larger to download and install on users' devices than it needs to be. Larger apps see lower install success rates and take up storage on users' devices."

how to fix this error

Comment: I guess it's just a warning message in orange color.

Comment: Well, the error code is telling you that you should optimize the app using Android App Bundle. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

It's only a warning, not an error.

For an app that small I wouldn't worry.

It's not something that's made its way into the Ionic ecosystem yet but I heard that if you open up your project in Android Studio and then do the build through there you can create an app bundle.

I'm not totally sure that its fully tested for Ionic so you might have issues with this, but Android have published a full guide:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle#get_started

This is what they say:

1. [Download Android Studio 3.2 or higher](https://developer.android.com/studio)—it's the easiest way
   to add dynamic feature modules and build app bundles.
2. [Add support for Dynamic Delivery](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery)
   by including a base module, organizing code and resources for configuration
   APKs, and, optionally, adding dynamic feature modules.
3. [Build an Android App Bundle](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/#reference) using Android Studio.
   If you're not using the IDE, you can instead [build an app bundle from the
   command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#build_bundle).
4. [Test your Android App Bundle](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle#bundletool) by using it to generate APKs that
   you deploy to a device.
5. [Enroll into app signing by Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423).
   Otherwise, you can't upload your app bundle to the Play Console.
6. [Publish your app bundle to Google Play](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/upload-bundle).